# Programmers editor with nice multiline regex editing and search and replace?

Tags: regex, refactoring, editor, text-editor, automated-refactoring

I am using Eclipse which not supports multi line regex Expressions (it is possible but it is not designed to do it). Can you suggest advanced editor which allow to enter such regex into nice multi line window.

I am skilled in regex so not asking how to do it but where I can do it efficiently - in readable way with simple copy paste - with some preview of changes.

For example I want refactor such code:

```
class some_name(object):
  def some_name(self):
    pass
```

Regex search:

```
class (some_name)\(object\):
  def (some_name)\(self\):
    pass
```

Regex replace:

```
class \1_new(object):
  def \2_new(self):
    pass
```

Result:

```
class some_name_new(object):
  def some_name_new(self):
    pass
```

Code is simplified to give better example but it can be more lines too. Can you suggest how to do it in efficient way.

Comment: What happens if the original source code has a different layout than your regex?

Comment: If layout is different you need use `\s+` in some places but for large part of codes there is not risk to use `\s+` since larger code parts is more unique code. You can replace all space to '\s+' with some assumption that is winning assumption but you need check it.

Comment: And if there are comments in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally use [sublime-text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) ([here is the documentation on the regex find and replace](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html)) for those things.

I tried with your example and this is a screenshot of the result after the replace:

[image: Sublime find and replace with regex]

One big advantage of using sublime is that it is extremely fast.

Comment: Perfect thing I create 2k lines of code at least and replaced 15 classes in at least 15 classes.